# lexer and Python parser

Tags: python

Inside the Python interpreter, which is a compiler that translates the source code into intermediate code and then interprets and executes the byte code.

But my questions before compiling and interpreting are:

If there is an unauthorized token in the code, at what stage does the syntax error related to the detection token occur? lexing or parsing

It is written in some places because the task of the lexer is to separate the signs of the language is meaningful and permissible, it gives an error at this stage.

In some places, hitting a meaningless token is considered unknown and is transferred to the next stage of parsing, where an error is taken.

Comment: At least recently, CPython didn't have a separate lexer and parser; because it was an LL(1) parser, lookahead was limited and the tokens were parsed as they were recognized. I think the new PEG parser introduce in Python 3.10(?) does separate tokenization and parsing into two distinct phases.

Comment: Yes, they are separate, but what did it have to do with my question?
I mean at what point is the wrong token error taken in Python?
Parsing or Lexing?

Comment: The point is, the answer to your question is "yes". Previously, there was no clear distinction between lexing and parsing in CPython.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you mean that Lexer and Parser are now two separate tools?

And we know that Lexer detects tokens.

Now the question:
An unknown or unauthorized token error such as $ is reported in Lexer and the program stops or in Parser?

Comment: In fact, in compiler languages, each step has its own error, but what about Python, which is an interpreter and the compilation process is different?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "compiler language". Any language can be implemented with an interpreter or a compiler, and *both* implementations still requiring parsing to get to an AST that can be interpreted or compiled.

Comment: Because in so-called compiler languages ​​like C # we have a semantic analyzer that detects errors such as undefined variables or ... and in general many errors are taken at compile time but in a language like Python which is so-called interpreter, the code if It has no syntax problem, it is compiled and most errors are detected such as an undefined variable at runtime.

Comment: So there are differences, such as meaning analysis, which does not exist in Python, or at least performs other tasks related to syntax, or in the Python virtual machine. So they may be different in this case as well. Anyway, I did not get the answer to my questions whether there is an error in Lexing and the program stops or not?